# Java Multiple Processes and Heap size

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

We have a legacy system that runs many many Jar files.
Each jar file is run in a separate process.
Some of these jar files have a spike in memory usage. As such, their heap limit is high(~128MB), although at any given moment most of them do not use that memory.

The problem is, that Java is under no pressure to deallocate memory. Since the garbage collector does not see the big picture, it is under no pressure to reduce heap size. As such each process allocates an excess heap of ~100MB (most of the time they need less than 30MB).

Multiply this behavior over many java instances, and you have a big problem. Is there any trivial solution, aside from re-writing all of the jars to to work from within a single JVM?

Comment: I have never heard of anything trivial. That's basically the point of all those application containers, however distasteful they may be.

Comment: [This is a great read](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4694058), BTW.

Comment: Do you actually encounter any memory issues? e.g. `OutOfMemory` exceptions?

Comment: @nif It's the opposite case: OP wants excess heap to be returned from JVM back to the OS, so *other* applications may use it.

Comment: @Marko: Yes, this is a very complicated server with some large C programs running on top. They are the ones running out of memory.

Comment: But out-of-memory problems are simply solved by increasing swap space. The issue with Java's process size is only that it will occupy/waste a part of the swap file. It can affect performance, eat some filesystem space, but shouldn't really cause other processes to starve.

Comment: @Marko: About your first comment, are there any application containers to run shared JAR files with Main(). Just like the ones for WAR files?

Comment: A WAR is nothing but a JAR with more structure, and possibly containing further JARs for its classpath. It is the answer to the request you describe. So no, you can't solve it without going the WAR/EAR route.

Comment: @Marko: I can't enlarge my swap, It is allready at 33GB. Like I mentioned, I am running many many small java processes. They are not web-apps, so I cannot use WARs. If I build my own custom loader, how would I avoid class-path conflicts between the different jars? example: Two jars use different versions of an external lib. Can I use Tomcat (or any other container) somehow for non web-apps?

Comment: How do you define a web app? You can package your stuff as a WAR and deploy it to Tomcat.

Comment: I need a way to launch an instance (one of many) of a third party JAR with a "main" from the command line. My machine basically runs alot of 3rd party jars on-top of it. Since they are not mine, I cannot change them not to run from a static "main". However I can deploy and launch them in creative ways. The problem with putting them in Tomcat, is that I fear that they might interfere with eachother, or with other instances of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

JVM has some options to control heap expansion / shrinking. For HotSpot this is

`MaxHeapFreeRatio`: Maximum percentage of heap free after GC to avoid shrinking.
`MinHeapFreeRatio`: Minimum percentage of heap free after GC to avoid expansion.

If the ratio between the used memory and free memory exceeds MaxHeapFreeRatio, JVM will shrink to `-Xms`. If that ratio is less than MinHeapFreeRatio then JVM expands.